# In Xamarin Forms UnityServiceLocator namespace not found (Unity Dependency Injection & IoC containers)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.forms, unity-container

I am facing the problem while implementing the Unity Container (Unity Dependency Injection & IoC containers) for not able to find the namespace for "UnityServiceLocator" in Xamarin Form.

I am getting the error at  **var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(Container);**

**error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityServiceLocator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I am using the .Net Framework 2.1 using Visual Studio 2019.

Nu-get Package Install as :

Unity (5.11.7)

CommonServiceLocator(2.0.5)

Xamarin.Essentials(1.3.1)

Xamarin.Forms(4.7.0.1.1080)

```
using System; 
using TestXamarinMVVM.Services;
using TestXamarinMVVM.View;
using Unity;
using CommonServiceLocator;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestXamarinMVVM
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static UnityContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Container = new UnityContainer();
            Container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>();

            **var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(Container);**
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);


            //MainPage = new PersonDispaly();
            MainPage = new ProductPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know where I am doing the mistake! Please help me.

Comment: Is this stuff likely to keep being supported? Seems like it's got very shaky support. It used to be one package distributed by Microsoft and now it's a open source package that needs separate pieces installed to work? Seems kind of rinky dink.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following packages for unity.

1. Unity
2. CommonServiceLocator
3. Unity.ServiceLocation

Answer (score 0):

The most recent way of doing this is [shown in this example below](https://github.com/QuiLeVan/UnityContainerXamarinDemo/blob/0ecd481d853c35ac30c39845c7393374a9674da5/UnityIoCContainer/App.xaml.cs). You will notice that you did make a few errors:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Init UnityContainer
        UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IProductsService, ProductsService>();

        var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);

        MainPage = new ProductsPage();
    }
```

But you also forgot to add the following using statements, which means you likely need to add more nuget packages:

```
using Unity.ServiceLocation;
using UnityIoCContainer.Interfaces;
using UnityIoCContainer.Services;
using UnityIoCContainer.Views;
```